# How can i extract data from webservice?

Tags: android, string, replace

I am using android to extract a message from webservice such as

Received: Bundle[{id=13, from=web, message=Test: 120, android.support.content.wakelockid=1, collapse_key=do_not_collapse}]

I want to extract the number 13 (in id=13) and 120 (in message=Test: 120). I used bel

```
String message = msg;//Such as above meassage
String[] separated = message.split(",");
String data_person_id=separated[0]; // this will contain id
String data_person_id_num = data_person_id.replace("id=", "");
data_person_id_num=data_person_id_num.trim();

String data_msg=separated[2]; // this will contain data of test
String data_msg_sort = data_msg.replace("message=", "");
String[] separated_dot = data_msg_sort.split(":");
String data_number=separated_dot[1]; // this will contain data
String data_number_nonspace = data_number.trim();
```

Comment: Is "Received: Bundle" part of the message?

Comment: Thank .  I got it. I just add         String data_person_id_num = data_person_id.replace("Received: Bundle[{id=", "");

Comment: You could also use a `String#substring()` method. Or `data_person_id.replaceAll("[^0-9]","")` to strip all non-numeric characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are working in Bundle. "A Bundle is basically a dictionary. Each value in the Bundle is stored under a key. You must know the type of value under the key. When you know the type, you access the value associated with the key by calling a method relevant for the type of the value (again, you must know the type)"

For example if the key is request and its type is String you would call:

```
String id= bundle.getString("id");
String message= bundle.getString("message");
```

After that, you can use split to cut the `:`